# SignalR trigger System.InvalidOperationException in Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, azure-application-insights

SignalR trigger System.InvalidOperationException in Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll every second.

How can I use SignalR with application insights?

It seems to do with the the SQL backpane: Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer

```
    public class UnwantedTelemetryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

        public UnwantedTelemetryFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
        {
            this.Next = next;
        }

        public void Process(ITelemetry item)
        {
            var request = item as RequestTelemetry;

            if (request != null && request.Name != null)
                if (request.Name.Contains("signalr"))
                    return;

            var dependency = item as DependencyTelemetry;
            if(dependency != null)
            {
                switch(dependency.Type)
                {
                    case "SQL":
                        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dependency.Data))
                        {
                            return;
                        }

                        break;
                }
            }

            // Send everything else:
            this.Next.Process(item);
        }

        public static void Set()
        {
            var builder = TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
            builder.Use((next) => new UnwantedTelemetryFilter(next));
            builder.Build();
        }
}
```

Error info:

```
Stacktrace:
at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Metrics.DependencyMetricsExtractor.ExtractMetrics(ITelemetry fromItem, Boolean& isItemProcessed)

Error:
    Message "Cannot execute ExtractMetrics because this metrics extractor has not been initialized (no metrics manager)."   string
```

This is how I start the Application Insights. It is executed in the Application_Start.

```
    public static void SetApplicationInsights()
    {
        #if(DEBUG)
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;
        #endif

        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
        string t = Settings.KeyVault.Global.GetKey("AppInsightsInstrumentationKey");
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
        {
            UnwantedTelemetryFilter.Set();
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = t;
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: confused about the question.  are you saying that you're getting an invalid operation exception out of application insights itself?  or out of your code that was posted.  if you're getting an exception, can you post the full stack trace?   if the stack trace is in AI's code, you should post it as an issue on our GitHub repo: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/

Comment: @JohnGardner it is not the code but in the output windows I just get that exception every second. It seems like it has something to do with the SQL. Everything is working however.

Comment: can you set a breakpoint on that exception and get a stack trace of it?

Comment: @JohnGardner I have updated the question with the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the new message you added with error info, you seem to be running into this GitHub issue:

[GitHub issue #549: DependencyMetricsExtractor.ExtractMetrics threw exceptions](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/549)

where it looks like if you manually added telemetry processors via code, you need to call initialize on them?

it looks like this specific issue was fixed a couple months ago, you may need to update to a newer version of the SDK, or use the workarounds specified in that issue